# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class PandasAI with abstract method chat

Tags: openai-api

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class PandasAI with abstract method chat when using pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import PandasAI
from pandasai.llm.openai import OpenAI

df = pd.DataFrame({
"country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
"gdp": [19294482071552, 2891615567872, 2411255037952, 3435817336832, 1745433788416, 1181205135360, 1607402389504, 1490967855104, 4380756541440, 14631844184064],
"happiness_index": [6.94, 7.16, 6.66, 7.07, 6.38, 6.4, 7.23, 7.22, 5.87, 5.12]
})

OPENAI_API_KEY = "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"
llm = OpenAI(api_token=OPENAI_API_KEY)

pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm)
pandas_ai.run(df, prompt='Which are the 5 happiest countries?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use smart dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import SmartDataframe

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
    "gdp": [19294482071552, 2891615567872, 2411255037952, 3435817336832, 1745433788416, 1181205135360, 1607402389504, 1490967855104, 4380756541440, 14631844184064],
    "happiness_index": [6.94, 7.16, 6.66, 7.07, 6.38, 6.4, 7.23, 7.22, 5.87, 5.12]
})

# Instantiate a LLM
from pandasai.llm import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(api_token="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")

df = SmartDataframe(df, config={"llm": llm})
df.chat('Which are the 5 happiest countries?')
# Output: United Kingdom, Canada, Australia, United States, Germany
```

You need to get the paid version of chatgpt it will not work on free version